# Does NASA police urine production by astronauts?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, astronauts, medical

Acute abdominal pain is a medical emergency which requires diagnostic facilities not available on board spacecraft. It could require emergency return from LEO or mission abort in cislunar missions. One of the causes of acute abdominal pain is renal stones.

> https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26456109
>
> Bone loss and renal stone risk are longstanding concerns for
> astronauts. Bone resorption brought on by spaceflight elevates urinary
> calcium and the risk of renal stone formation... Regardless of
> exercise, the risk of renal stone formation increases during
> spaceflight. A key factor in this increase was urine volume, which was
> lower during flight in all groups at all time points. Thus, the
> easiest way to mitigate renal stone risk is to increase fluid
> consumption.

Prolonged microgravity causes significant calcium loss in bones (10 times the rate seen in Earth-bound osteoporosis), thereby increasing the risk of kidney stones. https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/benefits/bone_loss.html

Between 1% and 15% of people globally are affected by kidney stones at some point. In 2015, they caused about 16,000 deaths worldwide… By far, the most common type of kidney stones worldwide contain calcium. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_oxalate#Kidney_stones

Acute abdominal pain in an ISS crewmember would necessitate return to Earth, along with the other crew in that Soyuz/Crew Dragon crew group. The same event on a Lunar mission would cause a mission abort. On a Mars mission...?

Since the risk of kidney stones can be reduced by maintaining adequate urine volume, "which was lower during flight in all groups at all time points", does NASA routinely “police” astronaut urine production (monitor urine production and enforce fluid consumption)?

Comment: Might it be less messy to police *fluid intake*?

Comment: Space travel is not for the squeamish! Dilution of calcium salts is critical. As well as oral fluid intake, urine volume is affected by perspiration, respiratory loss and metabolic water production . Urine collection also allows measurement of salt concentrations  and trace blood detection which can be the first diagnostic sign of stones.

Comment: AFAIK ([source](https://youtu.be/05oOst9kZXQ?t=365)) there is no on orbit processing of urine, so that would be a pretty *piss poor* (forgive me, I couldn't resist) response time for predicting kidney stones. (i.e., your urine gets back to Earth the same-ish time you do...)

Comment: Urine volume  can be measured in microgravity. Quantitative dipstick tests are available for everything from specific gravity, blood and chemistry to pregnancy. Dipstick urine testing has already arrived at the ISS https://blog.healthy.io/company-news/healthy-in-space

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 they process the urine on the US side of the ISS (or they did in 2014 when I got out of the game) https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49419/6944 https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26745/6944 https://space.stackexchange.com/a/45727/6944

Comment: @OrganicMarble good catch, I should have said *analysis*, like proposed in the question.

Comment: Woody can you define what you mean by "police"? Do you mean "monitor", or do you mean "enforce a certain amount of production per individual"?

Comment: @Woody Link indicates dipstick testing is *not* @ ISS yet **"Early next year, when the Ax-1 spaceflight docks at the International Space Station..."** (Axiom mission hasn't launched yet) & supports my *lack of* in-situ (analysis) claim: **" One factor complicating such research has been the need to capture urine in space, freeze it, and test it back on Earth..."**

Comment: By "police" I mean "monitor and enforce" rather than just measure. Urine volume... "which was lower during flight in all groups at all time points" indicates that self-motivated fluid intake by astronauts is insufficient to compensate for increased calcium excretion. This increases the risk of preventable mission-threatening medical emergencies.

Comment: different but related: [Does extended microgravity increase the rate of kidney stones in astronauts? Do these lead to medical complains/discomfort while still in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54422/12102)

Comment: @Woody, that "monitor and enforce" aspect should go into your question then, to make it clear what you're asking without reading into the comments...

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 Well, "Today's coffee is tomorrow's coffee!", as [Scott Manley couldn't help remind](https://youtu.be/SyCa6IVd7KI?t=309) coffee aficionado Christina Birch; the successful introduction of the system was cause for an [adequate toast](https://www.space.com/6733-astronauts-drink-recycled-urine-celebrate.html) in 2009.  The astonishing thing for me is that before recycling they must have launched tons of drinking water in supply runs during a mission, only to discard it into space. A no-go for a Mars mission for sure.

Comment: To continue this line of thought: On generation ships or other very long term missions the bodies of the deceased will most likely be recycled in one way or another as well, just as they are on spaceship Earth. Cixin Liu made a big drama of it in Trisolaris but in all reality it's not.

Answer (score 10):

For shuttle:

- There was no enforcement of and no policy existed regarding urine production per crewmember.
- Even if such a policy had been desirable, there was no way to monitor per-crewmember urine production.

The shuttle toilet (formally, "Waste Collection System (WCS)") had no telemetry associated with it. (See this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44964/6944) for a WCS overview) The responsible flight control group EECOM had to infer when toilet ops were ongoing by monitoring other signatures in the orbiter systems:

- AC current signatures from operation of the WCS fans
- Change in pressure over time (dp/dt) of the cabin atmosphere for a toilet flush
- Quantity changes in the waste water tank

[image]

Source: [Shuttle ECLSS Training Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/383445main_eclss_21002.pdf) (annotations mine)

*This answer does not apply to dedicated life science experiments such as those conducted during the [Spacelab Life Sciences](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/history/space-life-science.html) missions which may have monitored per-crewmember urine production using a Urine Monitoring System.*

Comment: Individual 24 hour urine collections were performed on ISS 3-6,8, and 11-14 as part of the potassium citrate stone prevention study. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20070008213/downloads/20070008213.pdf Results showed markedly lower stone formation risk with higher 24hr urine volumes.

Comment: @Woody your comment appears irrelevant to this shuttle-focused answer.

Comment: Since the shuttle no longer flies, the answer itself is irrelevant to the posted question. But the information in the answer is interesting so thank you for the contribution.