# Does gravity affect sweating?

Tags: gravity, physical-activity

I read [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/what-happens-to-astronaut-sweat-on-the-iss) hot question.
It's asked what is done with the sweat produced by astronauts in the ISS.
This led me to question: does gravity affect the production of sweat? Is more, the same, or less produced due to gravity?
Is more, the same, or less sweat produced in empty space?

Comment: There are no realistic prospects for being near a black hole.

Comment: I think if I unexpectedly found myself near a black hole and was still alive, I'd be doing a fair amount of sweating.

Comment: @Tristan Haha! And you'll probably have to vomit too. It's THE solution for losing weight! ;-)

Comment: @OrganicMarble I edited the question, sir Marble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sweat production depends on the activity level, clothing and air temperature.

Defining a test activity with exactly the same workload on Earth and in zero gravity in orbit is very difficult. You should be able to measure the exact workload to compare both workouts. The air temperature, humidity and flow should be the same.

To measure the amount of sweat produced is difficult, both liquid and vapor should be registrated.

An experiment like this would be very expensive to do in orbit, so there will be no answer to this question based on exact and comparable measurements.