# Pee processing in space

Tags: iss, water, waste, eclss

Do astronauts drink each their own pee or is there a common pee container where all pee get collected and processed? It's clear to me that the obtained water must be sterile, but even then, I imagine that people will feel psychologically better in the former case.

Comment: There is only one water recycling circuit (+ systems for redundancy) on the ISS. I remember hearing a Podcast about the water and air systems on the NASA Podcast (Houston we have a Podcast) some time ago if you want to get a detailed description.

Comment: ...astronauts do not drink urine.

Comment: I thought the Russian side had a system that made water for other things from it.  Kept getting clogged...

Comment: slightly related: [Did astronauts on the moon poop in front of each other?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32208)

Comment: I strongly recommend "Packing for Mars," by Mary Roach. It's a fascinating read into all things astronautical, including human waste collection and recycling, effects of not washing for months, and all sorts of wacky icky things.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff  "...that we know of"  :-)

Comment: To put it bluntly: anyone who demonstrated dislike of recycled /purified pee would have washed out of astronaut training very early in the process.  By the way, we **all** drink recycled pee.  Where do you think our fresh water comes from?

Answer (score 4):

At least on the US side of the ISS, there is one processor for all, the Urine Processor Assembly.

[image]

Source: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26629/6944 (see link for acronymology)